# Is F' = G(F)) a secure PRF given F and G are secure?

Tags: block-cipher, pseudo-random-generator, pseudo-random-function

If we have a secure PRF (, ) and a PRG G where  :  →  ×  is a secure PRG.
Is the PRF F'(k, x) = = ((, )) also secure?