# Does this function yields to a PRF?

Tags: pseudo-random-generator, pseudo-random-function

I have two PRGs:
$$G: \{0,1\}^l \rightarrow  \{0,1\}^{3l}$$

$$G': \{0,1\}^m \rightarrow  \{0,1\}^n ,  n \gg m$$

I also have a PRF:

$$F: \{0,1\}^{3l} \times\{0,1\}^m\rightarrow  \{0,1\}^m $$

Is:

$$\operatorname{F}'(k, x) = G'(F (G(k), x))$$

a PRF?

How can I actually prove this? I was trying defining two different hybrid games, the first would have simulated $F$, and the second for the entire $F'$, but actually I can't make the reductions work.

My sketch of the proof was the following:

I defined first the following Hybrid game:
$$Hyb_{\pi,A}(l)$$
Where I just substitute the part of the function:
$$\operatorname{F}'(k, x) = G'(F (G(k), x))$$

with:

$$\operatorname{F}'(k, x) = G'(R(k,x))$$

where the function $R$ is a truly random function:
$$R: \{0,1\}^{3l} \times\{0,1\}^m\rightarrow  \{0,1\}^m $$

Now I want to prove that my original $Game^{prf}_{\pi,A}(l) $ is computationally close to $Hyb_{\pi,A}(l)$, i.e.:

$$Game^{prf}_{\pi,A}(l)\simeq_c Hyb_{\pi,A}(l)$$

This is what I think the first part, but I'm not getting correctly how to draw the reduction correctly. Someone can help?

UPDATE: Now I'm thinking about this fact, if I control the key $k$ the construction can't be a PRF.
I can just start considering $G$ as a PRG that works as follows:
$$G(k) = G_1(k_{l/2},...,k_{l})$$ for which then I can control the result of the key, for example (where $U_x$ is a uniform $x$ bit string, and $0^y$ is a string of all $0$s with length $y$):
$$G(U_{l/2}||0^{l/2}) = G_1(0^{l/2}) = t$$
Now this $t$ is known to me right?
Then I can also predict the result of the original PRF $F$ and constructing $G'$ similarly to $G_1$ finally telling that $F'$ is not a PRF. Is this reasoning correct?

Comment: What about breaking this into two easier sub-problems, e.g. the first of which leaving $G'$ aside? [updated] Notice that straight dump of homework questions are closed, per [policy](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). E.g. this [related question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/98882/555). To avoid such outcome, you need to show what you attempted, even if it is imperfect.

Comment: @fgrieu So you mean that I have to consider first  $ F(G(k), x) $
and proving that this is a PRF and then I add $G'(F (G(k), x))$ and finally prove that yields to PRF? Yeah but I'm not getting what kind of reduction I have to do to prove it's a PRF.

Comment: [updated] yes that's what I'm thinking about; in the second step, you'd be considering extending from $\tilde F(k,x)=F(G(k),x)$ being a PRF to $G'(\tilde F(k,x))$ being a PRF if $G'$ is a PRG, with no consideration on $G$ needed. If you are stuck at the first step, perhaps indicate that in the question. It might help to also add to the question the formal definitions you have of PRF and PRG, or at least the textbook used as reference for these definitions, for the answer depends on that to some degree, I believe. I do suggest you include an attempt at the first step in the question.

Comment: @fgrieu Hi, I just updated with more detail my problem, and I also sketched my first idea of solution for this one. Thank you

Comment: I didn't really look in details but I am not sure if I follow the part *if I control the key $k$ the construction can't be a PRF*. On one hand, a PRF requires that the key is uniform random, on the other hand it seems that $k$ should have length $l$ to be consistent with $G$. So, the counter example with $G_1$ is a bit confusing, to me at least.

Comment: @MarcIlunga definetely I just started being mad, what I wrote doesn't make any sense at all.

Comment: Onto the question itself, my intuition would be that, in a sequence of games, you could replace $G(k)$ by a UR $k'$ and argue that step on the PRG security of $G$ and uniformity of $k$, then from there, replace $F(k', x)$ with a random value(based on PRF security of F). Then, ultimately, you could argue that the distribution of $F'$ is close to that of a random function. I'm not sure if this works but, it would be my initial attempt..